# Problem with recursion - just started with JAVA (and any coding for that matter)

Tags: java, recursion

I would expect `par(int [])` to be called again after meeting the below requirement

**`s2[0]== 40 && s2[s2.length-1] == 41`**

but instead it jumps straight to return false (first from the bottom). Btw. I added it only because Intellij would return an exception when running the code (no return statement) which I also dont get

Apologies for not using right language when explaining what's the issue. As mentioned in the title, I literally have 0 experience with coding

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "(([]))";
        int[] s2 = new int[s.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            s2[i] = s.charAt(i);}

        boolean z = par(s2);

            System.out.println(z);

        }

    public static boolean par(int[] s2) {
        if (s2.length==0)
            return true;

        if (s2[0]== 40 && s2[s2.length-1] == 41 || s2[0] == 91 && s2[s2.length-1] == 93 || s2[0] == 123 && s2[s2.length-1] == 125){
             s2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(s2, 1, s2.length-1);
        par(s2);}
        else return false;


        return false;

    }

    }
```

Comment: `par(s2);` is a bug in your recursion implementation. It should be `return par(s2);`

Answer (score 1):

In your second if statement, it should be `return par(s2);` instead of simply `par(s2);`. What is happening currently is that the function is making its way into that second if statement, performing `par(s2)`, THEN making its way into the else statement.